# Powershell form to convert string to base64 and back and write to file

Tags: powershell, base64

I have this function that I wrote that will Encode/Decode  strings in Base64 format.

I understand the end goal of what I am asking for might not make sense but it is something I have to do.

I have a `snp.txt` file with the contents `start notepad`

I need to convert that string in the file to Base64 and it should look like this:

`cwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAbgBvAHQAZQBwAGEAZAA=`

Then immedietely turn around and decode it right back to what it was to look like:

`start notepad`

However when I do that using the example below, when it is decoded back it returns:

`s t a r t  n o t e p a d`

I am not sure why the text has the spaces in it

```
function B64 {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="encString")]
param(

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encString")]
    [Alias("es")]
    [string]$encString,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decString")]
    [Alias("ds")]
    [string]$decString

)

if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encString") {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($encString))
        return  $encoded
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decString") {       
        $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($decString))
        return $decoded
        }
}
```

This is where I call the functions to first encode the string and then decode it back again returning:

`s t a r t   n o t e p a d`

```
$filePath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\snp.txt"

$encData = Get-Content $filePath
$enc = B64 -encString $fp;$enc | Out-File -FilePath $fp

Sleep 1

$dec = B64 -ds $encData;$dec | Out-File -FilePath $fp
```

Comment: This happens because you're using different encodings to encode and decode your string. Either ascii for both or uncicode for both. Preferably you should use UTF8. The encoding of the file should also match with the encodings used on your function.

Comment: put that as an asnwer so I can mark it right and you get your credit. Attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're using different encodings to encode and decode your string. Either ascii for both or uncicode for both. Preferably you should use UTF8. The encoding of the file should also match with the encodings used on your function. –
Santiago Squarzon